# xlookup formula with more than one criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

i am trying to match a value using xlookup formula to find `I1` in `A` and if `H1>C` and `H1<D` return `B` i have below this but cant figure out how to make it work `=XLOOKUP(I1,A:A,B:B,,IF(AND(H1>C,H1<D),B:B,"none"))`

i have an index and match that works but im trying to learn with xlookup with multiple critera
`=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,(C:C<H1)*(D:D>H1)*(A:A=I1),0)),"none")`

**update**

**well my bad excel 2016 does not support xlookup**

uploaded sample data G1 is where my index match formula is G2 is the xlookup

[image]

Comment: @P.b's formula works for me, returning "none" whether I use `1` or `I1` as the lookup reference - if you get rid of the full column references, you will likely get to the root of the problem if you select the `(C1:C12<H1)*(D1:D12>H1)*(A1:A12=I1)` part of the formula and press F9

Comment: @SpectralInstance tried your suggestions still no luck also suggestions of P.bs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same logic as your INDEX/MATCH solution:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,
         (C:C<H1)*(D:D>H1)*(A:A=I1),
         B:B,
         "none",
         0)
```

Where, just like with your MATCH `1` stands for `TRUE` and it looks up the first row where all the arrays return `TRUE`, then returns the value in that row from column `B:B` or if nothing's found it returns the built in IFERROR value: `none`.

[image]

Comment: tried it but still have error value,i even used ctrl+shift+enter, uploaded pic for sample data

Comment: Added screenshot of the formula in action with the data you shared in the screenshot (better to share using markdown table). It's probably a trailing space or character in the search value or the search column, or the dates are not dates, but text. Also it's better to use `<=` and `>=` to include dates that equal listed dates.

Comment: i checked the values those are dates and also no leading or trailing spaces used the suggestion by Spectral Instance and yours too still no luck, maybe its coz im using excel 2016? what do you mean by markdown table?

Comment: Excel 2016 does not support XLOOKUP

Comment: my bad, still accepted your answer, if i type "=" then "x" the xlookup function appears so i assumed it supported excel 2016 :)

Comment: Your index match solution is a good alternative. That it appears surprises me. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929